# AWK reference full row

Tags: awk

I am trying to add a column Date to a series of tab deliminated columns.

```
awk -v c=0 '{if(c==0){c++; print "Date\t" print} else{ ...
```

the file has plenty of columns, so I dont want to print each column with $x

```
print ( "Date\t" $1 $2 $2 ... )
```

but rather print the whole line just prepended by the new Date column. just the statement print nicely prints the line but I could not find an example of how to print something and then the full line in the same line. How can reference the full row such that I can do

```
print ( "Date\t" ROW_REFERENCE)
```

Comment: `$0` references the current line, so `print "Date\t" $0` would print `"Date\t"` followed by the current line.

Comment: you can also do the same with just changing `$1`, i.e. `$1="Date\t" $1` and  printing the line as usual.

Comment: You can also do `printf "Date\t"` to avoid the trailing newline.

Comment: Thanks, $0 was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from kdhp's comment

`$0 references the current line, so print "Date\t" $0 would print "Date\t" followed by the current line`